# How combineReducers know which slice to pass REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm little bit confused about how combineReducers will pass reducers their needed slice of state.

For example i my state looks like this:

```
{
    products: [somedata],
    comments: [somedata]
}
```

and I have 2 reducers for handling changes in them (1-productReducer, 2-commentReducer)

in my root reducer i have

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducer(
    products: productReducer,
    comments: commentReducer
)
```

Lets imagine products and comment are two different things and have no connection together and i want to just pass `state.products` to productReducer and `state.comment` to commentReducer. That so obvious I don't need  comments in `productReducer`. But how does this `combineReducer` handle this?!

If I want to do this I would write:

```js
function rootReducer(state, action) {
    products: productReducer(state.products),
    comments: commentReducer(state.comments)
}
```

But I wonder `combineReducer` even cares about slicing data and passing them to appropriate reducer.

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.ts#L139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see people are linking to the source code or the documentation but maybe a simple explanation will help you understand.

When you call combine reducers, each reducer will return it's initial slice of the pie, combine reducers simply takes this slice of the pie and stores it in a map using the same name as to which the reducer is registered, when an action is dispatched, it simply takes the slice it was stored for each reducer and passes it again in order to produce the next state.

you call:

```js
combineReducers({
  foo: fooReducer,
  bar: barReducer,
})
```

internally the state gets stored:

```js
combinedState = {
  foo: fooState, // the state returned by the initial call to the foo reducer
  bar: barState, // the state returned by the initial call to the bar reducer 
}
```

when an action is dispatched, something like this occurs:

```js
combinedState = {
  foo: fooReducer(fooState, action), // generate the next state
  bar: barReducer(barState, action), // generate the next state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`combineReducer(products: productReducer, comments: commentsReducer)`, will create single state object and differentiate between them using keys (products, comments) passed to it.

```
rootReducer = combineReducer(products: productReducer, comments: 
commentsReducer);
   // This would produce the following state object
  {
  products: {
   // ... products, and other state managed by the productReducer ...
  },
  comments: {
   // ... comments, and other state managed by the commentsReducer
  }
}
```

[Here](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/) this concept is defined.

**Update:**

`combineReducer` calls *all* reducers it's wrapping with action dispatched, giving reducers a chance to respond. Please [follow](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers/).

Comment: tnx but the output was clear to me. my question is that what part of main state will be passed to sub reducers. how does it know which part of state(e.g product) should be passed to its appropriate reducer(e.g productReducer

Comment: @Amas, Please refer to answer updates for your question.